# How to find the package name given a class name?

Tags: java, class, reflection, package

Given a class name as a string, how do I get the package name of it at run time ? I do not have the fully qualified name with package name + class name. Simply only the class name.

I want the package name to be used in `Class.forName()` method.

I am perfectly fine with finding the first matching package name (if multiple packages have the same class).

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I DO NOT have a Class instance to work on. My requirement is to create a Class using the `Class.forName()` method. But I simply have ONLY the class name as a string. I need some way to loop though the packages and identify if the class I have belongs to the package.

The stack trace of the exception is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyAddressBookPage
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
```

Comment: You don't need a class instance of Class.forName to work. Read the comments in my answer

Comment: Why are you voting everyone down? We are just trying to help. If everyone is giving similar answers then it means that you were not able to describe your problem well and its your fault in the first place..

Comment: An example of what you mean in terms of class name vs fully qualified class name may be useful in clearing up the confusion, e.g. "I only have 'Baz', I don't have 'com.foo.bar.Baz'.

Comment: @Cemre, it's not him, it's me. I'm voting them down because they're not answering his question. Don't take it personal! :) Once they're edited to be useful answers I'll go back and remove the downvote where it doesn't apply anymore. But currently, they're just not good answers. That's how we start the journey from no answer, to best answer on the web. Again, don't take it personally.

Comment: It wasn't me who down voted ANY of the answers.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. It's a bit intimidating to see my already low reputation go down. 
@Grundlefleck thanks for replying. ;)

Comment: @Cemre I generally try to avoid down voting, but because there was so many similarly wrong answers, no upvoted answers, and I found the question quite clear, I felt it was the right choice. Unfortunately I didn't realise there's a timeout on removing the downvote, so I can't undo them now there's some upvoted answers. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Grundlefleck If I guess right you can upvote them after an edit.

Comment: @rekire Looks like that's the case. Now there are reasonable upvoted answers I will remove the downvotes where I can (some still require an edit, as you say).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is most likely an incredibly inefficient, bloated, inconvenient way of doing what you're trying to achieve, and hopefully there's already an out-of-the-box, single way to do it... but it should work.

Basically, scan through every class in the class path, until you find a class where `getSimpleName()` matches the class name you have.

I recommend looking at [Google Classpath Explorer](http://code.google.com/p/classpath-explorer/) to help manage the nuts and bolts of doing this.

It could look something like this:

```
 ClassPath classpath = new ClassPathFactory().createFromJVM();
 RegExpResourceFilter regExpResourceFilter = new RegExpResourceFilter(".*", ".*\\.class");
 String[] resources = classpath.findResources("", regExpResourceFilter);
```

`resources` is an array of Strings like 'com/foo/bar/Baz.class'. You can now simply loop through and find matching entries, and transform them from slashed to dotted, strip out '.class', etc. Just be careful around trying to match inner classes, as they will have a '$' character in them.

Also, as far as I am aware, this will **NOT** cause those classes to be loaded.

Comment: I'd be careful about loading each class, apart from increasing the number of classes loaded any static initilaisation code will get executed, including code you won't want, e.g. attempt to do XWindows specific stuff on windows.  You could always restrict the search if you have some prior knowledge

Comment: As long as it works I am not worried about the performance. This is not a critical project. And the Google Classpath Explorer seems it might do the work :)

Comment: This looks brilliant, but when I load everything in and run it the application hangs. `findResources()` takes `rootPackageName` but when I load anything in there (i.e. "com.foo.bar" or "com/foo/bar") the code executes but `resources` comes back empty. Any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: Format for `rootPackageName` is "com/foo/bar". I still cannot get it to work in my Android application, but was able to get it to work no problem in a regular Java app. I wonder if there's something about Android that's preventing this from working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

```
 final Package[] packages = Package.getPackages();
    final String className = "ArrayList";

    for (final Package p : packages) {
        final String pack = p.getName();
        final String tentative = pack + "." + className;
        try {
            Class.forName(tentative);
        } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println(pack);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but there's one caveat: AFAICT this only works if at least one class from that package has already been loaded. Otherwise there won't be an entry in the `packages` array.

Answer (score 3):

The only way would be to navigate the directories/jars in classpath and an entry with the class name.

Here is some code that almost does what you want.  This code is part of a class I have that searches for implementations/factory methods for creating instances of interfaces.  Sorry, don't have the time to change this to look for a named class, should be an easy change, and as I mentioned elsewhere you don't need to load the class, just check the name.

```
public Class<?> locateImplementation(Class<?> type) {
     Class<?> c = null;
     String[] cp = System.getProperty("java.class.path").split(File.pathSeparator);

     for (int i = 0; (c == null) && (i < cp.length); ++i) {
         File f = new File(cp[i]);
         if (f.exists() && f.canRead()) {
             if (isJar(f)) {
                 try {
                     c = searchJar(type, new FileInputStream(f));
                 } catch (Throwable t) {
                     // Nothing to worry about
                 }
             } else {
                 c = searchFile(type, f);
             }
         }
     }

     return c;
 }

private boolean isClass(String path) {
    return path.matches(".+\\.class$") && !path.contains("$");
}

private Class<?> searchFile(Class<?> type, File f) {
    return searchFile(type, f, f.getPath());
}

private Class<?> searchFile(Class<?> type, File f, String root) {
    Class<?> implementation = null;

    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            implementation = searchFile(type, files[i], root);
            if (implementation != null) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } else if (isClass(f.getPath())) {
        String path = f.getPath().substring(root.length() + 1);
        Class<?> c = getClass(path);
        if ((c != null) && !c.isInterface() &&
                type.isAssignableFrom(c)) {
            implementation = c;
        }
    }
    return implementation;
}

private Class<?> getClass(String name) {
    Class<?> c;
    String className = name.replaceAll("[/\\\\]", ".")
        .replaceFirst("^\\.", "").replace(".class", "");
    try {
        c = Class.forName(className);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        c = null;
    }

    return c;
}


private Class<?> searchJar(Class<?> type, InputStream in)
        throws Exception {
    ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(in);
    Class<?> implementation = null;

    ZipEntry ze;
    while ((implementation == null)
            && ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null)) {
        String name = ze.getName();
        if (name.endsWith("class")
                && name.matches("^com.xxx.+")
                && !name.contains("$")) {
            try {
                Class<?> c = getClass(name);
                if ((c != null) && !c.isInterface()
                        && type.isAssignableFrom(c)) {
                    implementation = c;
                }
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                // Nothing to worry about
            }
        }
    }

    return implementation;
}

private boolean isJar(File f) {
    return f.getPath().endsWith(".jar");
}
```

Comment: So I will have to use I/O to find the file in the directory? No way of  using reflection to search through the packages?

Comment: Don't think so, the class you are looking for may not have even been loaded so would not be available.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest solution:

```
Test.class.toString().replace("class", "").replace(".","/").replace(" ", "")
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Given a string with the name of a class, for example `"ArrayList"` you need to find the package name, for example `"java.util"`

Answer (score 0):

Call getPackageName() on the class. It returns the fully qualified package name. Also, it is worth mentioning that this is a Java 9 feature.