# Identify the application that using library in android

Tags: android, shared-libraries, java

Well in my android projects I use a common library for developing different applications

**Let me elaborate :**

I got Library package called `com.example.library`

and i have two application based on this library

`com.example.app.english`  and `com.example.app.german`

My question is .

Is there any way to identify the `application_name/package_name` or any details of application that using my `library` inside my library package

**NB:**Sorry for my bad english  Hope all understand my need

Comment: Why do you need to know the application_name/package_name?

Comment: @MattWolfe Wolfe Wolfe because my library contains some strings in resource-XML on the base which app is being used i need to provide values to application

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742965/how-to-find-the-package-name-given-a-class-name

Answer (score -1):

You can use project as a library than right click on project and select properties and checked is library.

after that use this library project to any project than right click and select properties 
and click add to library.

Comment: i didn't ask for how to add a library to project