# Getting Dynamic class name and package name in reflection in java

Tags: java

I have a issue I want to a class in reflection dynamically from different package. And for this I have used 
`String p="proj"; //user input
 Class reflectclass= Class.forName("javaapplication8."+p);`

Now the problem is I have to load package also dynamically like if the user gives the class name I am able to load it package dynamically.
I serached and probably found out that we can get package dynamically through
`String c=reflectclass.getPackage().getName();`

Now, whats happening is I have to on load package before relectclass so that I can replace it with `"javaapplication8." --> c` to get the class but reflect class cannot execute without the package name. I am deadlock condition. And I have an only class name from the user which is in a different package.

So whats the solution so that I can get both reflect class as well as package names both. I have tried inserting 
`String p="project"; 
  String c=p.class.getPackage().getName();` but it doesn't work...

Comment: How do you get the package name to "load"? Why not just `Class.forName(packageName + "." + p)`?

Comment: @ernest_k I have to get the package of the class dynamically...I dont have the packagename...

Comment: So you mean you have to scan the entire classpath to find a class which matches the name ignoring the package name

Comment: If the class is not in the default package, then you can't load it with just its simple name. In other words, you are having incomplete information to load the class. So your input should be either the fully qualified class name, or the combination of simple class name and package name.

Comment: Please check below link for your answer to scan class from each packagae and find out correct package.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742965/how-to-find-the-package-name-given-a-class-name

Comment: @ernest_k ... is there a way we can get package name before the reflectclass... class name is provided by user in form of string provided by user ....

Comment: mentioned the way to find out package name from class name then he can load the user defined class with found package

Comment: @KPP sorry but thats not a solution it just retrieving all the classes from project and my project consist of thousands and thousands of classes and I cant loop them all.. any better idea...

Comment: RegExpResourceFilter regExpResourceFilter = new RegExpResourceFilter(".*", "proj.class");

provide your class name it will give you exact package and if you have same class name in different package then it will give one and more result